# Scrapy: Changing media pipeline download priorities: How to delay media files downloads at the very end of the crawl?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

> When the item reaches the FilesPipeline, the URLs in the file_urls field are scheduled for download using the standard Scrapy scheduler and downloader (which means the scheduler and downloader middlewares are reused), but **with a higher priority, processing them before other pages are scraped**. The item remains “locked” at that particular pipeline stage until the files have finish downloading (or fail for some reason).

I want to do the exact opposite: Scrape all HTML urls first, then, download all media files at once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but if you're curious to know how this behavior is implemented, check `MediaPipeline` pipeline source code, especially the [`process_item` method](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/pipelines/media.py#L42):

```
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        info = self.spiderinfo
        requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
        dlist = [self._process_request(r, info) for r in requests]
        dfd = DeferredList(dlist, consumeErrors=1)
        return dfd.addCallback(self.item_completed, item, info)
```

You see that a bunch of requests are queued, to be processed (request sent + response downloaded) BEFORE `item_completed` is eventually called, returning the original item + the downloaded media info.

In the nominal case, requests generated by the `MediaPipeline` subclasses will be sent for download immediately [by using `crawler.engine.download` directly](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/media.py#L78):

```
        (...)
        else:
            request.meta['handle_httpstatus_all'] = True
            dfd = self.crawler.engine.download(request, info.spider)
            dfd.addCallbacks(
                callback=self.media_downloaded, callbackArgs=(request, info),
                errback=self.media_failed, errbackArgs=(request, info))
        return dfd
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to evaluate the "best" way to go: 1. During the html crawl, store all files path in a queue then launch another scrapy spider to handle all files at once (simple solution) or 2. Derive from the media pipeline (elegant solution), but I also need to store all files path in a persistent queue in this case... If you can head me in any direction? I am not that interested in downloading files, but rather in detecting if they are available (200 or 404) and get their size in kb